# Using Regular Expression Search to parse and format HTML Tag in Rss

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-7, rss

I have content:encoded text like below from an rss:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<P><B>Wednesday, September 26, 2012</B></P>It is Apple.<P>Shops are closed.<br />Parking is not allowed here. Go left and park.<br />All theatres are opened.<br /></P><P><B>Thursday, September 27, 2012</B></P><P>Shops are open.<br />Parking is not allowed here. Go left and park.<br  />All theatres are opened.<br /></P>]]></content:encoded>
```

Using the below method I am able to extract the text from the HTML:

```
public static string StripHTML(this string htmlText)
    {
        var reg = new Regex("<[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(reg.Replace(htmlText, string.Empty));
    }
```

But I want the text within `<b></b>` to be inserted in a dateArray[] and text within `<p></p>` to be inserted in descriptionArray[] so the I can display like below:
[image]

tHANKS iN aDVANCE.

Comment: c#... you have some good html parsers (agilitypack for instance). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is what is said about regexes to parse html in stack overflow. Have fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var result = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(n => n is HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode)
                .Select(n=>new {
                    IsDate = n.ParentNode.Name=="b" ? true: false,
                    Text = n.InnerText,
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This error is showing "The type 'System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"

Comment: I got it. I have to add reference to System.Xml.XPath from SDK folder.